# Changing label of xfs root file system

Tags: linux, centos, boot, xfs

I'm running a centos 7 server.
I want to change the label of the root file system (xfs).
`xfs_admin -L "newlabel" /dev/mapper/centos-root` fails because it can't operate on a mounted filesystem.

Is it possible to change label of mounted filesystem?

Is there a way to run something like that during boot before the root fs is mounted?

Answer (score 6):

The ability to update the label of a mounted XFS file system was
recented added.  August 2018 for upstream code and November 2018 for
RHEL/CentOS 7 packages.

Update the label like this (as root):

```
xfs_io -c "label -s MYNEWLABEL" /MNTPOINT
```

From the xfs_io man page:

> label [ -c | -s label ]
>          On filesystems that support online label manipulation, get, set,
>          or clear the filesystem label.  With no options, print the
>          current filesystem label.  The -c option clears the filesystem
>          label by setting it to the null string.  The -s label option
>          sets the filesystem label to label.  If the label is longer than
>          the filesystem will accept, xfs_io will print an error message.
>          XFS filesystem labels can be at most 12 characters long.

For upstream code this required Linux kernel >= 4.18 and xfsprogs >= 4.17.0.

For RHEL / CentOS 7 this required packages kernel >= 3.10.0-957.el7 and xfsprogs >= 4.5.0-17.

References:

- [linux commit f7664b31975bd893 "xfs: implement online get/set fs label"](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=f7664b31975bd893190708e76b2c424328f0c49b)
- [xfsprogs commit cfa10b0f972005b3 "xfs_io: add label command"](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/fs/xfs/xfsprogs-dev.git/commit/?id=cfa10b0f972005b38ed294bca66cebf2f65298ec)
- [Red Hat Bug 1322930 - [RFE] Allow xfs to modify labels on mounted filesystem](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1322930)
- [RHSA-2018:3083 - Security Advisory](https://access.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2018:3083)
- [Red Hat Bug 1584912 - [RFE] Allow xfs to modify labels on mounted filesystem (userspace component)](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1584912)
- [RHBA-2018:3274 - Bug Fix Advisory](https://access.redhat.com/errata/RHBA-2018:3274)

Comment: thanks, that was very useful. I had to follow it up with a "partprobe" before the label appeared in /dev/disk/by-label

Answer (score 0):

From man xfs_admin

> Devices  that  are  mounted cannot be modified.  Administrators must unmount filesystems before xfs_admin or xfs_db(8) can convert parameters.  A number of parameters of a mounted filesystem can be examined and modified using the xfs_growfs(8) command.

Comment: I know. That is exactly what I'm trying to find a solution to... This is the root file system so you can't unmount it. This is why I asked in my question if there is a way to run some command/script before the root file system is mounted during boot

Comment: Well, since the documentation says it can't be done, I would say you're searching in vain.